# Quiverplot adds a number to the plot in top right corner

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

I have an xarray's dataset (DS in the code below) with geophysical data.
When I am plotting it using quiver, a dot with a number appears in the top right corner, outside of the plot's range: [the dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuOKI.png).

I have eliminated everything piece by piece (axes by cartopy, land features, all of the different plot layers, gridlines), and found that this is the minimal code that gives me this issue (not including library imports, dataset import and handling etc.):

```python
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10), dpi=120) #adjust to change figure size and resolution

DS.plot.quiver(x='longitude',y='latitude',u='U',v='V',pivot='mid',zorder=2)
```

This is not a problem with data: regardless of the data I use, the dot with the same number appears in the same place.

EDIT:
Here's a full example with simplified data that suffers the same issue:

```python
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

#create Dataset
U=[[1,2],[3,4]]
V=[[3,4],[1,2]]
latitude=[[30,31],[29,30]]
longitude=[[-5,-6],[-4,-8]]
Along=[1,2]
Across=[6,7]
B=xr.Dataset(data_vars=dict(U=(['Along','Across'],U),V=(['Along','Across'],V)),coords=dict(latitude=(['Along','Across'],latitude),longitude=(['Along','Across'],longitude),Along=(Along),Across=(Across)))

#plot and save figure - the weird dot in the corner is more visible in the saved picture
B.plot.quiver(x='longitude',y='latitude',u='U',v='V')
plt.savefig(os.path.join(r'S:\System files\OneDrive\Pulpit', 'output.png'),dpi=150, pad_inches=0.1) #add filepath to save figure
```

Comment: If the problem doesn't depend on the data, maybe you could create a fully reproducible example including simplified test data, the exact libraries and data handling? As others don't seem to have the problem you mention, it is probable your issue originates somewhere in the code that isn't shown. Could you also mention the versions of the libraries involved? Are you calling `quiverkey(...)` in the code that created the plot?

Comment: I'm not calling quiverkey.
I have added full example with data to the post.

Comment: It was indeed the quiverkey, even though I haven't added it manually! Adding ```add_guide = False``` solved the problem!
It's weird how when plotting my original data it was just a tiny dot instead of an arrow.
Thanks for help!